# Solving for first term in vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I'm trying to solve a system of equations for a physics application I've been working on, and I'm down to one thing left that's stumping me. Essentially, I need to solve

$$A \times B = X$$

where $A, B$, and $X$ are vectors, and $B$ and $X$ are known and $\times$ is the cross product. All vectors have three components.

EDIT - I do also know that all three vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Are you able to expand the cross product and then use Gaussian elimination to isolate $A_1$? If the answer is no, let me elaborate within some minutes, unless somebody gives you an answer first.

Comment: I did try expanding the cross product into a system of equations, solving for each component of A, but I ended up with a singular matrix. I may well have been doing something wrong, I'm going to give that another go tomorrow morning.

Comment: If all three vectors are orthogonal, can't one then find A  by computing 
$B\times X=\pm A$?

Answer (score 1):

Your question would have been more readable by denoting $X$ the unknown: $X\times A=B$.

If the three vectors are orthogonal, then the equality holds for the norms: $\|X\|\|A\|=\|B\|$, and
$$X=\frac{\|B\|}{\|A\|}\frac{A\times B}{\|A\times B\|}=\frac{A\times B}{{\|A\|}^2}.$$